# Add overlay to line geometries in symbology

Tags: qgis-3, symbology, line, overlapping-features, overlay

In QGIS 3.22, I have a MultiLineStringZ layer with crossing geometries and I would like to represent either the Z component with overlay, or be able to order the geometries so that the last ones are above the first ones.
What I have :
[image]
What I would like :
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In QGIS, choose the **Layer Properties**. In the **Symbology tab** check the option – **Control feature rendering order**. Click the **Order** button.

From there you can choose a field from the layer to use to draw in either Ascending or Descending order.

You might have to create this field and manually assign the values to the features to get them to draw in the order you prefer.